# Buttons to navigate between view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have been looking for a way to fix an issue I've been having for days but after many google searches and searches here I am still unable to fix it. I am very new to iOS programming but took a short 4 week "crash course" and learned a few things.

So currently I have three view controllers set up and want to switch between each one using buttons so that if a user is at the first page they can go to either the second or third and from that page they can go back to either page they want.

This is what I have in the first view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Galleries.h"
#import "JotForm.h"

@interface MainView : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *galleryButton;


@end
```

Then in the implementation file I have this to handle the switching to the new view.

```
- (IBAction)galleryButton:(id)sender {
Galleries *gallery = [[Galleries alloc]initWithNibName:@"Galleries" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gallery animated:YES];
}
```

As of right now when I run the program it starts but when I click the gallery button it does nothing. How do I get it to switch to the next view? I have not used a navigation controller because I want to have the three buttons at the top of the app in each view and couldn't figure out how to do that with a navigation controller. Essentially I don't want any back buttons to be used when switching from page to page.

Thanks for any help anyone may be able to provide.

Comment: Its sounds like `UITabbarController` will be apt for you instead of buttons to navigate

Comment: It doesn't sound like you understand what view controllers are and what your options are. My discussion might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I click the gallery button it does nothing ... I have not used a navigation controller

Well, there's your problem. You are sending a message to `self.navigationController`, but it is nil (because, as you say, you don't have one) so nothing happens.

If you don't want a navigation controller, then I would suggest using `presentViewController:...`; you can't push without a navigation controller.

Comment: Is it possible to add in coding to make the new view controller load in from the left or right instead of looking as though it comes up from the bottom?

Comment: You get some other animation options, or (in iOS 7) you can write your own custom transition animation and do anything you want.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I have very little experience with all of this.

Comment: Did you look at the URL I gave you already? Teaches you all about this.

Comment: Ah no I didn't even realize it sorry, but thanks I'm an EE major trying to learn iOS programming over the summer as a hobby. Any other suggestions for me to help me learn?

Comment: I don't feel comfortable answering that question, and if you look at my bio (click on my name), you will see why.